# Is it possible to keep input query to 1 line (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

Just learning in Python 3, doing function building.  I have a set of functions that take in multiple elements from the user and output the unique elements.  I'm wondering if I can improve the program appearance because if there are large number of inputs they chain together, one after the next, each on a new line.  Ideally, every time a user hits enter the input line takes the element and the same line resets for the next value.

Here's what I have:

```
userlist = []
uniquelist = []

def make_list(list): #function to assign only unique list values
    for u in userlist:
        if u not in uniquelist:  #only append element if it already appears
            uniquelist.append(u)
        else:
            pass
    print("The unique elements in the list you provided are:", uniquelist)


def get_list():  #get list elements from user
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i += 1  #start loop in get values from user
        value = input("Please input some things: ")
        if value == "":  #exit inputs if user just presses enter
            break
        userlist.append(value)  #add each input to the list
    make_list(userlist)

get_list()
```

The output (in Jupyter Notebook) adds a Please input some things: line for each element a user inputs.  50 inputs, 50 lines; looks sloppy.  I cannot find a way to have the function just use a single line, multiple times.

Comment: Just omit the prompt. You can use the `iter` function to replace the `while` loop with `for value in iter(input, ""): userlist.append(value)`, or simply `userlist = list(iter(input, ""))`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the map function to take input in a single line and then split every data and then typecast it to form a map object and then pass it to the list function which would return a list in the variable like this:

```
var = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

Comment: It's Python 3: `raw_input` doesn't exist and `map` creates an iterator rather than returning a list (and certainly not an array).

Comment: sorry I didn't see that it was asked for python3, I corrected it so now it works in python 3.x

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't explaining (asking) correctly.  The user enters something and presses enter.  They are then given another prompt.  Pressing enter while blank breaks the input loop.   I was hoping to find a way for Python to not keep presenting new lines - and instead offer the same line over again each time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to clear the text in the console after each input? Then you could use `os.system('CLS')` on Windows or `os.system('clear')` on Unix systems:

```
import os

os.system('CLS')
user_input = ''
while user_input != 'quit':
    user_input = input('Input something:')
    os.system('CLS')  # Clear the console.
    # On Unix systems you have to use 'clear' instead of 'CLS'.
    # os.system('clear')
```

Alternatively, I think you could use [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).